# How to properly cement fill a small hole next to a foundation for a 100 year old beach house built on pier & beam foundation?

Tags: foundation, cement, hole

In summary, there is a small hole in the ground that has formed in about a 6 inch gap between a cement walkway and the cement foundation wall for an old beach house (over 100 years old). The beach house was built on a pier & beam foundation, on top of beach sand. The crawl space is very dry, there's nothing under there but sand. This is located in a hot & dry climate area where it rarely ever rains, and definitely never snows. What is the best type of cement to use to fill the hole? Should gravel or rocks be poured into the hole before pouring in the cement?

Note: When looking down into the hole only beach sand can be seen down in there, because the house is located in a beach community where all the houses are built on sand. All of the houses in the area are built very close together with maybe about 6 feet between houses, and all of the houses are very close to the street. The house is located on a hill so rain water easily drains towards the sidewalk and street and flows on down the street towards the ocean. This small hole has slowly formed due to the occasional rain storms eroding the sand over the course of decades of time. Instead of filling the hole back in with more beach sand, which would just continue to erode again in the future, it seems a better solution would be to fill the hole with cement to prevent further erosion of the sand.

Comment: Why not just fill it with sand and top with gravel?

Comment: How deep is the hole?  This is important to know, as a deep hole could indicate sinkhole activity under the structure.   In that case your insurance company may need to be called for an analysis to be ordered.  Pics could help us here , not to determine sinkhole activity, but to opinionate on whether more examination is needed.

Comment: Address the runoff that is causing the erosion, and shovel in some sand. Or don't address it and shovel in some sand more often. Concrete usually fails to fix shifting sand issues, the issues just move a bit and undermine the concrete.

Comment: Address the root cause. That's the runoff itself. Or it's the removal of plants. You might search for a low maintenance local plant that can tolerate the local rain variability and sand. Some plastic plus decorative rock could work too.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it its purely cosmetic, not structural.  Assuming that you can see the bottom of the hole, I would just get some quick drying instant concrete mix.  And follow the instructions on the bag.

There is a dry mix variety that you fill and then pour water on top, or you can get one that you have to mix.  If you don't have a wheelbarrow, you can mix it in a large empty paint bucket.